# Why is an Access query dropping rows due to an empty string in a column, not involved in the conditional expression?

Tags: ms-access, dataset

So I have 12 rows in a table, 3 rows have MetricParent = 'Begin!' and 3 rows have MetricParent = Null, and 6 other rows with MetricParent = 'someValue'. In a very simple query the three rows that have MetricParent = Null are being dropped, the query returns only 6 lines, but it should return 9.

```
SELECT Metrics.ID, Metrics.ApplicationName, Metrics.UserName, Metrics.MetricName, Metrics.MetricParent, Metrics.StartTime, Metrics.EndTime FROM Metrics WHERE MetricParent <> 'Begin!'
```

The MetricParent field is a ShortText size 255, Required No, Allow Zero Length Yes, Indexed No,...
There are no other required fields or indexes fields accept Metrics.ID all 12 rows of which have legitimate values

Why is this query only returning 6 lines, and dropping those where MetricParent = Null
I have seen that I can work around with one of two ways, by including an additional condition: "Or MetricParent is Null"  Or by wrapping the field in the select list and the condition with Nz:
i.e Nz(MetricParent,'')  but surely this should not be required, it is a not required field.

Can anyone shed any light please on why I need to be explicit with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MetricParent is both a "returned filed" (i.e., appears in the select clause) and it is "involved in the conditional expression" (i.e., appears in the where clause).

> As far as Access is concerned, Null doesn't equal anything. You can't
> use the Equals operator (=) to find null values. Nor can you use the
> Inequality operator (<>) to exclude them. (This isn't always true
> outside Access.) [10 tricks for handling null values in Microsoft Access](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/10-tricks-for-handling-null-values-in-microsoft-access/)

You're using MetricParent in the where clause, so if you want to return values to include rows where MetricParent is null, you will need to explicitly include them (i.e., WHERE MetricParent <> 'Begin!' or MetricParent is null).

Comment: OK I must be getting old - I have been using Access professionally for years - and whilst I can see from the results this is the case, I dont remember a single instance of this happening before. But then I cant say categorically that I have used the field with Nulls in the WHERE clause. Still, never going to stop learning!! Thanks mate.